# Can I say that a file was safe from power failure based on modification date?

Tags: windows-10, file-corruption

My pc with Windows 10 was continuously running this cycle.

> 1. Generate training data
> 2. Rename the training data
> 3. Train the neural network
> 4. Save the neural network
> 5. Test the neural network

Step 3 is typically completed 1 minutes after Step 2 is completed. My PC undergoed a power outage.

I found that the modification date of the neural network was 1 minute after the modification date of the second latest training data, which is in the past of the modification date of the latest training data.

Can I be sure that no data is corrupted at all? In this case I have to believe that the power failure ocurred inside the 1-minute window of Step 3. Or can it be the case that the neural network is corrupted but the modification date is somehow unchanged?

Comment: No one can know, without more data, its asking for opinions.  Restart it.  If its that important then perhaps get a UPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can not.

- There's a thing called silent corruption, and it's called that to indicate data can be corrupt even if everything looks normal. It does not even require an abnormal power-interruption, it can happen due to cosmic rays even.
- Assuming your storage device is a SSD and although these have mechanisms in place to counter corruption due to unsafe shutdowns, an unsafe shutdown is an established potential cause for (silent) data corruption.
- I have never heard anyone argue an intact modification date implies any kind of guarantee with regards to validity of the data inside the file.

Is your data corrupt? No one can answer that.